# how to generate word cloud from csv

Tags: r, word-cloud

I have a diabetes dataset which consist of different attributes that are labeled "Yes" and "No" etc. as shown in the picture

dataset example

[image]

Thus, how possibly generating a word cloud which represent the frequency of all the attributes could be done? appreciate your help!

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data.

Comment: Another question: "_a word cloud which represent the frequency_" Do you want a word cloud (with words with different sizes) or do you want a numerical representation of the frequency?

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow; definitely there are better ways to show the data. 
I aim to represent the words with different sizes. thanks for your assist!

Comment: You could use `dput(head(NameOfYourDataFrame))` and put the `structure()` output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```r
library(wordcloud)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Age, Gender)) %>% 
  filter(value == "Yes") %>% 
  pull(name) %>% 
  wordcloud()
```

This should give a wordcloud. There are several arguments for formating (colors, fonts etc).